# Formik keep ols values before render the news

Tags: react-native, formik

I'm using React Native and have two files: EditGiftScreen.js, which renders the page to edit a gift, and GiftForm.js, which renders the form. I also utilize it for my AddGiftScreen.js with different props.

My issue arises when accessing the edit feature after editing another item. The first time I access it, the fields are filled with the values of the older gift, and then the update is applied. However, I want to directly display the new values. I've attempted using a key on the form, employing another state on the GiftForm, and resetting the form when the component is unmounted, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have an idea?

**EditGiftScreen.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import api from "../../interceptors/api.js";
import GiftForm from "./GiftForm.js";
import Title from "../Title/Title.js";

function EditGiftScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { giftId, selectedChild } = route.params;
  const [apiError, setApiError] = useState(null);
  const [gift, setGift] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Faites une requête à votre API pour récupérer les détails du cadeau
    api
      .get(`/gifts/${giftId}`) // Assurez-vous que l'URL est correcte
      .then((response) => {
        setGift(response.data);
        setApiError(null);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        setApiError(
          `Une erreur est survenue lors de la récupération du cadeau du cadeau, veuillez écrire à ${process.env.CONTACT_EMAIL}.`
        );
      });
  }, [giftId]);

  const handleEditGift = async (values) => {
    try {
      await api.patch(`/gifts/${giftId}`, {
        name: values.giftName,
        url: values.giftUrl,
        details: values.giftDetails,
        price: parseFloat(values.giftPrice),
      });
      setApiError(null);
      if (selectedChild) {
        navigation.navigate("ChildrenList", { currentChild: selectedChild });
      } else {
        navigation.navigate("MyList");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      }
      console.error(error);
      setApiError(
        `Une erreur est survenue lors de la mise à jour du cadeau, veuillez écrire à ${process.env.CONTACT_EMAIL}.`
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Title title="Editer une envie" />
      {gift && (
        <GiftForm
          initialValues={{
            giftName: gift.name,
            giftUrl: gift.url,
            giftDetails: gift.details,
            giftPrice: gift.price.toString(),
          }}
          onSubmit={handleEditGift}
          btnTxt={"Mettre à jour"}
          key={gift.id}
        />
      )}
      {apiError && <Text style={styles.apiError}>{apiError}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 20,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  apiError: {
    color: "red",
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});

export default EditGiftScreen;
```

**GiftForm.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import { giftValidationSchema } from "../../utils/validationSchemas.js";
import FormInput from "../Form/FormInput.js";
import FormButton from "../Form/FormButton.js";

function GiftForm({ initialValues, onSubmit, btnTxt, key }) {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Mettre à jour les valeurs du formulaire
    setFormValues(initialValues);
    setIsReady(true);
  }, [initialValues]);

  return (
    <>
      {isReady && (
        <Formik
          initialValues={formValues}
          validationSchema={giftValidationSchema}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          enableReinitialize={true}
          key={key}
        >
          {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, values, errors, touched }) => (
            <View style={styles.form}>
              <FormInput
                label="Nom du cadeau"
                placeholder={"Entrez le nom du cadeau"}
                value={values.giftName}
                onChangeText={handleChange("giftName")}
                error={touched.giftName && errors.giftName}
              />
              <FormInput
                label="URL du cadeau"
                placeholder={"Entrez l'URL du cadeau"}
                value={values.giftUrl}
                onChangeText={handleChange("giftUrl")}
                error={touched.giftUrl && errors.giftUrl}
                keyboardType="url"
              />
              <FormInput
                label="Détails du cadeau"
                placeholder={"Taille, pointure, couleur, etc"}
                value={values.giftDetails}
                onChangeText={handleChange("giftDetails")}
                error={touched.giftDetails && errors.giftDetails}
                required={false}
              />
              <FormInput
                label="Prix du cadeau"
                placeholder={"Entrez le prix du cadeau"}
                value={values.giftPrice}
                onChangeText={handleChange("giftPrice")}
                error={touched.giftPrice && errors.giftPrice}
                keyboardType="numeric"
              />
              <FormButton title={btnTxt} onPress={handleSubmit} />
            </View>
          )}
        </Formik>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  form: {
    width: "80%",
    rowGap: 15,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default GiftForm;
```

Versions :
`"formik": "^2.4.3", "react": "18.2.0", "react-native": "0.72.6",`

Answer (score 0):

You are picking the existing values from an API. Which you use to pre-fill the form. This date is stored in the parent component i.e. EditGiftScreen.js

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // Faites une requête à votre API pour récupérer les détails du cadeau
    api
      .get(`/gifts/${giftId}`) // Assurez-vous que l'URL est correcte
      .then((response) => {
        setGift(response.data);
        setApiError(null);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        setApiError(
          `Une erreur est survenue lors de la récupération du cadeau du cadeau, veuillez écrire à ${process.env.CONTACT_EMAIL}.`
        );
      });
  }, [giftId]);
```

I believe the issue lies in the state you are passing for initialValues. Before the api call succeeds and fills it with new data. It contains stale data, which is why you are seeing old data which then updates after millisecond or so.

#### Solution

In your onSubmit, reset the gift to its initial value after a successful submit. I recommend you to implement a loading and success flag so you can track this state better.

```
  const handleEditGift = async (values) => {
    try {
      await api.patch(`/gifts/${giftId}`, {
        name: values.giftName,
        url: values.giftUrl,
        details: values.giftDetails,
        price: parseFloat(values.giftPrice),
      });
      setApiError(null);
      setGift(null); // ADD THIS LINE
      if (selectedChild) {
        navigation.navigate("ChildrenList", { currentChild: selectedChild });
      } else {
        navigation.navigate("MyList");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      }
      console.error(error);
      setApiError(
        `Une erreur est survenue lors de la mise à jour du cadeau, veuillez écrire à ${process.env.CONTACT_EMAIL}.`
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hi, I've already attempted this, but it hasn't made any difference. When I access another gift in edit mode, the old information still briefly appears for a quarter of a second before the values in the fields get updated. I suspect it might be a bug with Formik because when I log the gift on each page, I receive the correct gift initially.